# understanding Azure File Storage: UnknownHostException

Tags: java, azure

Edit: I just realised that AccountName, below, refers to a storage account, which I have not yet created. I thought it was just the general azure "Account", that I have. Disappointing.

I am working through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/storage/files/storage-java-how-to-use-file-storage?tabs=java) Java/Azure File Storage example. I have been met with a problem, which I have been unable to find a resolution for:

In English: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-java-how-to-use-file-storage?tabs=java

createFileShare exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: failed to resolve 'my-provided-accountname.file.core.windows.net' after 2 queries

I am unsure of what *exactly* to provide for AccountName and, to a lesser extent, AccountKey, which I think is correct.

My obfiscated code:

```
    public static final String connectStr =
        "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;" +
                "AccountName=my-provided-accountname;" +
                "AccountKey=87D2A2E999180C4A624E1A8153CEBD6";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AzureFileStorageApplication.class, args);
    ShareClient shareClient = new ShareClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(connectStr).shareName("testfilestorage")
            .buildClient();
    createFileShare(connectStr,"hello1A");
}
public static Boolean createFileShare(String connectStr, String shareName)
{
    try
    {
        ShareClient shareClient = new ShareClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectStr).shareName(shareName)
                .buildClient();

        shareClient.create();
        System.out.println(shareClient);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("createFileShare exception: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an English link for that tutorial?

Comment: I have provide a link, maybe tutorial was too strong a word. Click "this", above.

Comment: my bad;https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-java-how-to-use-file-storage?tabs=java

Comment: I am in Germany, where chrome takes me to the English automagically.

Comment: I haven't actually used Azure File Storage, but I would expect the URL to be `https://<name>.file.core.windows.net/`, not just `<name>.core`

Comment: well, I don't know what to tell you, the url was decided upon by ShareClientBuilder

Comment: You were correct; I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Azure doesn't like, I assume, the camelCase I was using for the file name. Changing it to the following worked:

```
 createFileShare(connectStr,"hellishheat");
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should create an Azure Storage Account
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?tabs=azure-portal

and paste it in the code. Example:

```
AccountName=myazurestorageaccount;
```

When Azure Storage Account is created, get AccountKey(as described in link below)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-keys-manage?tabs=azure-portal

and paste it in the code. Example:

```
AccountKey=87D2A2E999180C4A624E1A8153CEBD6;
```

Java ShareClientBuilder documentation describes instantiating a Share Client with connection string.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.file.share.shareclientbuilder?view=azure-java-stable

```
String connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={name};AccountKey={key};"
 + "EndpointSuffix={core.windows.net}";
ShareClient shareClient = new ShareClientBuilder()
 .connectionString(connectionString).shareName("myshare")
 .buildClient();
```

In you case you should append *"EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";* to your connectStr.

```
public static final String connectStr = 
    "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;" +
            "AccountName=my-provided-accountname;" +
            "AccountKey=87D2A2E999180C4A624E1A8153CEBD6;" + "EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
```

Comment: Illegal character in authority at index 8: https://my-provided-accountname.blob.{core.windows.net}

Comment: I updated my answer. EndpointSuffix should be without brackets. EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net

Comment: I removed those brackets, and still: createFileShare exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: failed to resolve 'my-account-name.file.core.windows.net' after 2 queries

Comment: Are you sure that your Storage Account has name my-account-name? 
Azure Storage Account name can contain only lowercase letters and numbers.

Comment: i have edited the question, to point out that I have no storage account. Duh

Comment: First you should create Azure Storage Account. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?tabs=azure-portal